# Executing commands from command line to socket.io server

Tags: javascript, command-line, socket.io

I've been experimenting with socket.io nd got it working pretty well! But I would like to be able to do some maintenance work from my command line, so I can command my server.

Is there a way to have the socket server (server.js) listen to commands coming from bash/command line/terminal aswell?

Comment: What type of commands? Are you expecting a fully interactive terminal that can run `vim`, or just running things that output data, like `cat`.

Comment: I'm more looking for it to listen and respond to commands I might program in. So if I'm running a simple chat server, I might want to have commands like kick *username* and stuff like that, that can only be executed from bash/commandline/terminal.

Answer (score -1):

You can use putty (or any other terminal emulator) to connect to your server's port and send it commands directly.

Comment: Alright, I could do that. But I'm actually looking for something more directly into my terminal.
Since I'm already in there, running the program. I'd feel there's a way it could respond to what I'm entering there instead of just monitoring...